# Create a shorter version of a huge table (similar to a view)

Tags: mysql, database, view, triggers, foreign-keys

I have this huge table (Species) that contains millons of records and there's another database that has a FK to Species.

However, from the Species table only a subset are valid foreign keys. Let's say around 50,000 records.

I know I can't create a view because I can't use a view as the parent table for a FK.

So, I'm thinking on having a small version of the Species table, let's say ValidSpecies that contains a copy of the 50000 records.

However, is there an easy way of doing this so that when I modify the Species (big) table the ValidSpecies (small) table gets updated automatically to reflect the same changes?

Comment: Why would you need to do this in the first place? Can you elaborate on the need? A table with millions of rows woud work just fine (and would be fast).

Comment: Doesnt work fast at the moment on our server. And because that table would be much easier to do queries (to get evern smaller subsets of the valid species)

Comment: It's possible with a composite foreign key with `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. But without a clear context, I wouldn't recommend it, since it can introduce new performance issues.

Comment: Edit your question and add the table schema, including indexes.

Comment: Sounds more like a badly configured MySQL server for some reason as MySQL should normally handle tables records in the millions/billion number just fine when indexes are used..  like @TheImpaler already said.. Or the server is running on normal HDD 's ?